# Check syntax errors in rule file of Drools

Tags: drools, drools-flow, drools-guvnor

I am new to Drools Guvnor and have set up a basic rool framework using the same. I just want to know if current Drool file is correct or not.

As of now, I have no way except running it end to end. Is there any to check compilation issues immediately?

EDIT:

When we have syntax errors, for example, 'string.Contains' instead of 'string.contains' validate/verify pass successfully and so does 'Build Package' option. Let me know If I am missing anything.

Apart from this, I don't have much idea about QA section (in fact, we haven't put any test there).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Guvnor you can

1) Validate individual rules by *Source -> Validate* menu, (can be seen when rule is open)

2) Define and run a test scenario using QA section. Guvnor [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-guvnor-docs/html/ch04.html#d0e1919) has a nice section describing its use.

3) Use *Validate Configuration* and *Build Package* buttons on *Edit* tab of your package. This will compile all rules in your package.

I suggest you use use validate menu on every edit to a rule, and write test scenarios that cover 100% of your rules.

Comment: when we have syntax errors, say, 'string.Contains' instead of 'string.contains' validate passes successfully and so does third option. Let me know If I am missing anything.

Apart from this, I don't have much idea about QA section (in fact, we haven't put any test there). I will try that (any good tutorial/examples will be helpful). Thanks!

Comment: You can see the chapter in Drools manual about test scenarios. http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-guvnor-docs/html/ch04.html#d0e1919 can you provide a sample rule with syntax errors, that drools fails to deect at validate?

Comment: if(string.Contains('hello')){} although 'C' should be 'c' in 'contains', Drool's Validate/Verify don't detect it.

Comment: I have tried the "contains" example and Guvnor 5.4 gave the correct error messages. Can you please post the rule in question?

Comment: I am using Drools 5.3. Can  it be the reason?